Designing my first PCB, using solid state relays and two inductive loads, want to make sure that I understand how the circuit works I have it made
I'm making a DIY automated greenhouse and I think the safest way to have all of the components powered and talking to each other would be to design a PCB. I've never done that before and there is a lot to learn. I have two inductive loads (a fan and a solenoid water valve) and I have them controlled via an Arduino activating two solid state relays. This is the relay that I chose, and I want to make sure I understand a few things correctly before I send the design in to be manufactured.
One concern that I have it whether or not I understand how the relay should get its signals. I think the datasheet says that the LED should receive 1.64 V and 10 mA in order to operate. I tried to put two resistors in the circuit to drop the voltage from 5 V to 1.64 V at 10 mA, but I'm not sure if this would work, if my math adds up, or if there's a better strategy to try instead.
My other question is on the Schottky diodes that I want to use for inductor flyback. In my circuit, the switch is operating the low side of the inductor, and I wanted to make sure that this would still work for reverse EMF protection. I've been trying to conceptualize it and I feel like it should be irrelevant which line is being switched as far as the current is concerned, but it also feels like there's something that I'm not considering.
Lastly, I was told that these are NMOS low side switches and wouldn't work on the 12 V+ line. What confused me is that Digikey said that they would work for switching AC power, and I wouldn't think of AC power having a high or a low side. Any clarification on that would help, and I wanted to if it would be worth it to look for high side switches instead. The main concern is safety and even though it's only 12 V, it would still be connected to a water valve at all times and that makes me a little itchy.
This is my first time doing anything like this, and I really want to understand how it all works. I'm doing this as an opportunity to learn, so any insight or information would be greatly appreciated!




Is there a specific reason you’re using expensive opto relays and bypassing the isolation feature? Looks like you could use cheaper logic level n-Chan mosfets.  The 164 Ohm resistors are not needed. To calc the series resistor, (5-1.64)/0.01  = 330R. It is not necessary to be too precise with the actual value -an E12 value is sufficient vs E96. Why the earth fill on the top side?

If you’re worried about ‘safety’, you need to do a bit more work. Each component has a possibility of failing. How would you detect and mitigate this?

You're tossing away any benefits from using the opto-isolated MOSFET SSRs by having a common ground. In that circuit you'd save cost and complexity (and probably gain a bit of efficiency) by simply using N-channel MOSFETs. Or have a separate galvanically isolated supply for the loads & separate the grounds for better immunity. If it's your first cut, maybe give the two grounds different net names, and separate them well, and join them at one place with a jumper (or you could use a 'net tie' that is easy to cut). That way you don't need to respin the board (on that account) if you have issues.

@Kartman To be honest, I ended up with relays because I have experience with them as a technician and it felt like a good way to incorporate what I already know into this project. I started with two magnetic relays but thought that changing them to SMD opto relays would save on space and make things simpler. I'm using NMOS to control growlight intensity and I wanted to use as many different components as possible to learn more about electronics in general. However, I don't have experience with relays in the context of PCB and I didn't look into deeper applications.

@Kartman As for the earth fill on the top layer, the two reasons that I heard that manufacturers sometimes wont fabricate two layer PCBs with one layer of ground pour due to warping. I thought that it might also be better to have ground surrounding all of the components on the board to help mitigate crosstalk. That's something that I'm still learning about and don't have any experience with yet, but I added the top pour because I figured it might help a little bit and wouldn't hurt.

@Kartman as for safety, I have a circuit breaker and a GFCI switch that will be connected from the 12 V power to avoid obvious failures. The rest will mainly be handled by the Arduino programming which will look for signals from sensors/interlocks and put the system into an emergency off state if anything doesn't seem right. One thing that I haven't put in is reverse polarity protection since I'll be soldering in all the connections one wire at a time. Also, thanks so much for your response, as well as clarifying how I can drop the voltage correctly. I have much more research to do!

@SpehroPefhany I understand now, to be honest I chose relays because I have experience with them as a technician and they seemed like a simple go-to. That being said, I didn't look into their deeper applications in the context of PCB and didn't even realize that my circuit negated one of their strengths. I have NMOS set up to control LED growlight intensity already, it sounds like I'm best off just getting two more for the fan and water controls as well. Thanks a lot for your feedback
